# Unix command to make file and folders recursively

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I know `mkdir -p` will make directories recursively.

I know `touch` will create a file recursively.

I know `mkdir -p foo/bar; touch foo/bar/baz.txt` will work, but is there a flag or something for `touch` so I can one-step this?

I'm sure this question has been asked before a million times but for some reason I'm coming up empty.

Comment: there are no options to `touch` that will allow this. However, you can write a shell function that combines the two calls. Good luck.

Comment: assume that what you are doing is already one step. Otherwise search for "make_path in linux"

Comment: Eh, it's a bummer it's not DRY, but I've lived this long without it. make_path doesn't come with bash and seems more like a Perl function so I'll probably just do without. Thanks everyone. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function mytouch { for x in "$@"; do mkdir -p -- `dirname -- "$item"` && touch -- "$x"; done }
```

usage:

```
mytouch aa/bb/cc/dd.txt --a/b/c/d.txt -a/b/c/d.txt

$ ls -- aa/bb/cc/dd.txt --a/b/c/d.txt -a/b/c/d.txt                                                    
--a/b/c/d.txt   -a/b/c/d.txt    aa/bb/cc/dd.txt
```

Comment: You're not doing it well here: there are LOTS of quotes missing. Also, this won't work if called as, e.g., `mytouch -hello`. And even when you fix all the quotes, because of `dir=$(dirname "$1")`, you won't be able to have trailing newlines in `dir`, e.g., `mytouch $'a/b/c\n/d`.

Comment: pluse-uno for "Do one thing and do it well", as it doesn't seem that the O.P. has absorbed a key point of unix/linux philosophy,  but I think gniourf_gniourf has some valid comments. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 5):

what about an alias or a function:

```
function my_touch {
  mkdir -p $(dirname $1) && touch $1
}

my_touch /tmp/a/b/aaa ; ls -l /tmp/a/b/aaa
```

Answer (score 2):

The GNU implementation of `install` can do this:

```
install -D /dev/null foo/bar/baz.txt
# will create an empty baz.txt file in foo/bar
```

If you're using OS X without `coreutils` you have to use functions, like already suggested

Comment: Good alternative. Can you check if will pass the `mytouch $'a/b/c\n/d` test in   @gniourf_gniourf 's comment above. Good luck to all.